# Apache-ant not compiling

Tags: ant

I have set my ANT_HOME to appropriate path but while doing an Ant Compile it says ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or cannot be located.

I was able to do an Ant Compile before with the same system variables

can anyone suggest to set ANT_HOME  through command line

Comment: What's your OS? How do you set your env varible? Where does your Ant locate on your machine? `it says ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or cannot be located.` -- who output this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it,I was setting `ANT_HOME` to the parent directory `\bin`. I corrected it and it's working now.

In `ANT_HOME` variable set the path till `c:/apache`

and in path environment variable set the path=`c:/apache/bin`

This has solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for formatting it @gturri